# Add multiple lines to bezier plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bezier

Its a continuation of my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482405/drawing-arcs-between-x-and-y-axis?noredirect=1#comment79922932_46482405).

I have figured one way to plot the arcs between x and y axis using Bezier package.

```
import bezier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nodes = np.asfortranarray([
[0  , 10.0],
[500, 10],
[1000  , 0],
])

print nodes
curve = bezier.Curve(nodes, degree=2)
curve.plot(100)


nodes1 = np.asfortranarray([
[0  , 20.0],
[1000, 20],
[2000  , 0],
])

print nodes1
curve2 = bezier.Curve(nodes1, degree=2)
curve2.plot(100)


plt.show()
```

Its not clear from the manual, but I want to add the all the curves to a single plot. The above code generates two separate plots. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `curve.plot(100)`, it returns the `matplotlib` [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) object that it created the plot on. You just need to grab that handle:

```
ax = curve.plot(100)
```

If you feed that `Axes` object to the subsequent `curve2.plot` call, both curves should be plotted on the same axes.

```
curve2.plot(100, ax=ax)
```

You can see the [documentation here](https://bezier.readthedocs.io/en/0.5.0/reference/bezier.curve.html?highlight=plot#bezier.curve.Curve.plot). Here's the complete script:

```
import bezier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nodes = np.asfortranarray([
[0  , 10.0],
[500, 10],
[1000  , 0],
])

print nodes
curve = bezier.Curve(nodes, degree=2)
ax = curve.plot(100)


nodes1 = np.asfortranarray([
[0  , 20.0],
[1000, 20],
[2000  , 0],
])

print nodes1
curve2 = bezier.Curve(nodes1, degree=2)
curve2.plot(100, ax=ax)


plt.show()
```

[image]

To keep adding more curves, just make sure you add `ax=ax` to each `.plot` command:

```
nodes2 = np.asfortranarray([
[0  , 30.0],
[1500, 30],
[3000  , 0],
])

print nodes2
curve3 = bezier.Curve(nodes2, degree=2)
curve3.plot(100, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I add multiple 'ax' to curve2.plot(100, ax=ax) if I have many more curves ?

Comment: You're looking at it the wrong way round I think. You can create many more curves in the same way as above, and with each one, just add `ax=ax`, and they will all be created on `ax`

Comment: @gthm See my edit, which shows how to add another curve

Comment: Thanks for being so patient. Really appreciate it.